# Proxy to either Rails app or Node.js app depending on HTTP path w/ Nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ruby-on-rails, node.js

On Ubuntu 11, I have Nginx correctly serving either CouchDB or Node.js depending on the path, but am unable to get Nginx to access a Rails app via it's port.

```
server {
    rewrite ^/api(.*)$ $1 last;

    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3005/;
    }

    location /ruby {
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9051/;
    }


    location /_utils {
       proxy_pass        http://127.0.0.1:5984;
      proxy_redirect    off;
      proxy_set_header  Host $host;
      proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_buffering  off; # buffering would break CouchDB's _changes feed
    }

    gzip  on;
    gzip_comp_level 9;
    gzip_min_length 1400;
    gzip_types  text/plain text/css image/png image/gif image/jpeg application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/x
ml+rss text/javascript;
    gzip_vary  on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
}
```

/ and /_utils are working bu /ruby gives me a `403 Forbidden`

Comment: Is the service on port 9051 getting the request proxied to it correctly?